# Как поменять "Рабочий стол" на "Desktop'?

Tags: windows, path, desktop

Мне нужно, чтобы в пути не было русских символов. Как поменять "Рабочий стол" на английский?

Comment: Вы не поверите, но `%userprofile%\desktop` в Windows — это вполне корректный путь к рабочему столу. Другое дело, что если в имени пользователя есть кириллица, то проблема все равно останется.

Comment: Я когда открываю путь до папки на рабочем столе, то в этом пути вместо необходимого Deskop вижу "Рабочий стол" и софт в котором работаю не распознает русский символы.

Comment: Вы путаете локализованные названия известных папок и файловые пути.

Comment: @Yaant в общем случае рабочий стол может быть перенесён в другую папку, и этот путь может оказаться некорректным

Comment: @andreymal Так-то да, но, исходя из заголовка вопроса, можно предположить, что до таких тонкостей автор вопроса еще не дошел. :)

Comment: @SirJegor просто в проводнике показывается `Рабочий стол`, на самом деле он `Desktop`:)

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы решить данную проблему надо избавиться от OneDrive, но у меня это сделать не получилось, поэтому нашел альтернативный вариант. Надо кликнуть пкм на системную папку - > свойства -> расположение -> поменять "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Рабочий стол" на "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop". Готово! Теперь весь путь состоит из латиницы.

Answer (score 0):

Реально рабочий стол может располагаться в папке:
`C:\Users\...имя пользователя...\Desktop`
Можно пользоваться этим путем, - он направит на рабочий стол.

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы сам путь к папке на рабочем столе, когда я её открываю, был полностью на английском.

Comment: C:\Users\Ya\Desktop\NewPapka - это путь, который я скопировал у себя с проводника (вверху), открыв папку, только что созданную на рабочем столе.
Путь полностью на английском.

Comment: C:\Users\djego\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\lab2 - у меня путь с "Рабочим столом"

Comment: Интересно... А Windows какая - XP, 7, 10, 11?

Comment: У меня windows 10 pro

Comment: У меня тоже Win 10.
А если зайти в диск с Windows, далее папки Пользователи - djego, там найти папку "Рабочий стол", у неё правой кнопкой вызвать контекстное меню, выбрать Свойства, открыть Расположение. Там какой путь расположения рабочего стола указан?
У меня C:\Users\Ya\Desktop

Comment: Таким способом C:\Users\djego\Desktop

Comment: C:\Users\djego\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\lab2 - а это, похоже, папка не на рабочем столе, а в облачном хранилище OneDrive

Comment: @janeya, не вводите людей в заблуждение. Папка пользователя не обязана располагаться в c:\users. Она может быть перемещена в другое место средствами windows.